# How to populate a String Array from a JSONObject to use in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have an android/java task where I want to get JSON values into a String array to display in a ListView and I am not sure where to begin? Thanks.

```
private String[] values;
...
// this is what is returned from the web server (Debug view)
// jObj = {"success":1,"0":"Mike","1":"message 1","2":"Fred","3":"message 2","4":"John","5":"message 3"};

try {
   if (jObj.getInt("success") == 1) {
      .
      // what i'm trying to do here is iterate thru JObj and assign values to the 
      // values array to populate the ArrayAdapter so that the ListView displays this:
      //
      // Mike: Message 1
      // Fred: Message 2
      // John: Message 3
      //
      .
      this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values));
      ListView listView = getListView();
   }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` to add values retrieved from Json Obejct and then set ArrayList for ListView as data-source. change your code as:

```
 ArrayList<String> array_list_values = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
       if (jObj.getInt("success") == 1) {

        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("0"));
        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("1"));
        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("2"));
        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("3"));
        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("4"));
        array_list_values.add(jObj.getString("5"));
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, array_list_values));
                ListView listView = getListView();
            }
     }
catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
  }
```

EDIT :
if number of messages is not always the same it may 1 to a larger number then you can Iterate JsonObject as:

```
 ArrayList<String> array_list_values = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
       if (jObj.getInt("success") == 1) {

        Iterator iter = jObj.keys();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = jObj.getString(key);
        array_list_values.add(value);
        }


        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, array_list_values));
                ListView listView = getListView();
            }
     }
catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but the number of messages is not always the same it may 1 to a larger number, so I guess I should use a for loop maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that and use the awesome GSON library:

```
InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
APIResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, APIResponse.class);
```

With:

```
Public class APIResponse{

public String 0;
public String 1;
public String 2;
public String 3;
public String 4;
public String 5;
public String succes;

}
```

But this won't work as you need to find an other name that 0,1,2,3,4,5 for the variables.

Please change this on server side

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String value0 = jsonObject.getString("0");
```

or 
in for loop

```
String tempArray[] = new String[5];
```

just do

```
for(int i=0;condition;i++){
    tempArray[i] = jsonObject.getString(String.ValueOf(i));
}
```

and pass the array to adapter